# Hash does not contain 'try' method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.8.7, rails-3.0.10

I am noticing differences between a hash object within Ruby 1.8.7 and a hash object within Rails 3.0.10.

For example, within the 1.8.7 `irb`, I get:

````
1.8.7 :001 > {}.try(:method)
NoMethodError: undefned method `try' for {}:Hash
from (irb):1```
````

However, from the 3.0.10 rails console, I get:

```
1.8.7 :003 > {}.try(:method_x)
NoMethodError: undefined method `method_x' for {}:Hash
  from (irb):3:in `try'
  from (irb):3
```

This surprises me because I was under the impression that [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) is defined in Object which is an ancestor of Hash and `try` will return nil instead of throwing a NoMethodError.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> This surprises me because I was under the impression that `try` is defined in `Object` which is an ancestor of `Hash` and `try` will return `nil` instead of throwing a `NoMethodError`.
>
> What am I missing?

Your impression of which *class* `try` is defined in is correct (`Object`). What you are missing is what *file* it is defined in. It's defined in the ActiveSupport library, not in the Ruby core library.

So, you need to

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/try'
```

first.

Comment: Yeah, I discovered that Rails monkeypatches Object and adds in `try,` which was a surprise to me.

Answer (score 1):

`try` is not part of ruby 1.8.7, though Rails does include it through `ActiveSupport`. `try` is part of `Object` from ruby 1.9+ (afaik).

Comment: No, `try` is not a part of Ruby even post 1.9